# Sum of array elements by order until target reached or end of the array reached

Tags: c++, algorithm, logic

Let's say that I have this array:

```
int A[6] = {1, 7, 2, 4, 3, 9};
```

And I have the target number at 6. We want to add the numbers until target reached or at least close to the target.

**The numbers that comes first have bigger priority**, so it would look like this:

```
Add 1 and 7, which results in 8. 
8 is bigger than 6, so ignore this sum and  keep 1. 
Add 1 and 2. 
1 plus 2 results in 3, which is smaller than 6, so we go to the next element after 2, 
     while holding the successful result.
Right now, result is 3, and the next element is 4, but 3 plus 4 is bigger than 6, 
     so we don't do anything with our result, and go to the next element. 
Result is still 3. 
3 plus 3 is 6, so we succesfully reached our target. 
We don't need to check the last element (9). 
In the end, we added 1, 2 and 3.
```

Another example:

```
int B[4] = {5, 4, 3, 2};
```

Procedure:

```
Add 5 and 4. 
Result is bigger than 6, so ignore the sum and keep 5. 
Add 5 and 3. Still bigger than 6, ignore the sum and keep 5. 
5 plus 2, 7. Bigger than 6 again. 
The final result is 5. 
In the end we didn't add anything, and kept 5.
```

I can't seem to figure the code for this pattern.

**EDIT:** I've come up with a code that works. Also, it executes until there's no leftovers in the array, dividing the array into parts, redoing the process until theres no element left in the array to be processed. Here it is:

```
int array[5] = { 500, 1000, 500, 500, 400 };
int arraySize = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);

int i = 1;
int j = 0;
int sum;
while (j < arraySize)
{
    sum = 0;
    sum += array[j];

    while (i < arraySize)
    {
        if (sum + array[i] <= 1500)
        {
            sum += array[i];
            array[i] = 0;
            i++;
        }
        else
            i++;
    }
    if (sum != 0)
        cout << "Part " << j + 1 << ": " << sum << endl;
    j++;
    i = j + 1;
}
```

In this example, we have the target number at 1500, with this array:

```
int array[5] = { 500, 1000, 500, 500, 400 };
```

The code returns

```
Part 1: 1500
Part 2: 1400
```

it does the same procedure as the other two examples that I gave, but redoing it with all the elements:

```
Add 500 and 1000, which results in 1500.
1500 is the target number, so doing a sum is not needed anymore, 
so it prints the first part that fit in the target, 
while maintaining the priority protocol.
Now, add 500 (the 3rd element) plus 500, which results in 1000.
1000 is smaller than 1500, so we keep going.
1000 plus 400 is 1400, which is smaller than 1500, but is the last
element, so we finish here.
```

Well, the code works, but it was kind of a "trial and error" success. Also, **I have a new problem**, which is: getting the indexes of the elements that were successful in the sum. It should print something like this:

```
Part 1: 1500
0, 1
Part 2: 1400
2, 3, 4
```

Comment: The problem seems fairly straightforward. Have you tried solving it yourself? If so, please show the attempt, as it helps to know where you're stuck.

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed what you've tried, posted code, and said what you expected, what didn't happen, etc.  You might start by describing the solution in English, with specific enough wording that someone else doing what you said would arrive at the answer.  Then it should be easy to write in code.

Comment: Hello, thanks for being interested in my problem. I've edited my question with some new information. Thanks!

Comment: The edit is a big improvement. However, you shouldn't frame it as a solution, but as an attempt, and the question could just focus on "how do I get the indexes that correspond to the sum?"